# Property wrapper into property wrapper

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I've made an IOC container with Swinject to manage my dependency injection and I've tried to pair that with some property wrappers :

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Inject<T:ObservableObject>{
    let wrappedValue: T = SwinjectContainer.resolve(ObjectType: T.self)
}
```

Next step is to use this property wrapper into my view ... but with another property wrapper `@StateObject`, but this goes wrong because my wrapped value does not match with `@StateObject`objectType, which needs to be an `ObservableObject`.

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @StateObject @Inject var VM:MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(VM.A ?? 23)")
            Button(action: {VM.B()}){
                Text("click")
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            VM.appear()
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a good approach to manage my dependency injection, and is it possible ?

Comment: you should use `@State` instead of `@StateObject`

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection in SwiftUI views works best via `@EnvironmentObject`, however that might not fit your use case. Also the code in the question doesn't look like something that qualifies for DI.

ViewModels should either be directly instantiated by the View, or injected from upstream at initialization time. VM's are not to be circulated through the whole app, they should be localized to the part of the application where the UI for them resides.

Dependency Injection should be reserved for global objects, like API clients, Cache providers, Persistence managers, etc. Those objects should then be consumed by the ViewModel objects, and you'd use Swinject on the hierarchy of VM's.

This way you also get a good separation of concerns: SwiftUI views only render the data provided by the VM's, and if needed send commands to them due to user interaction. Views are then unaware of any other business objects besides VM's, while the VM's rely of the injected objects to do the work.